# jquery access second class

Tags: jquery, class, fonts

I have the following structure on a website I am building

```
<td class="header link" id="link-XXX"><a href="/XXX>XXX</a></td>
```

I am using jquery to change the background color upon selection of the table. What I would like to accomplish is also make the font of XXX go to bold upon selection (which is controlled by link class).

I am using 
`$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#link-XXX).css('background-color', '#EBA521');
});`
to change the background color and it works

How do I access the link class and change the font of XXX to bold?

I tried

```
$("#link-XXX").css('font-weight', 'bold);
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: I suppose you forgot to add the single quote above to close `bold` and wrap `td` with `tr` and `table` otherwise one of these breaks it.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the anchor instead, like so:

`$("#link-XXX a").css('font-weight', 'bold);`

To make this even better, I'd suggest adding/removing a class to the `<tr>` or `<td>` every time the row is selected/de-selected. And then control the style of the `<td>` or `<a>` using CSS, like so:

```
.selected a
{
   font-weight:bold;
}
```

You can add/remove class by doing this

`$('#link-XXX').addClass('selected');`

and

`$('#link-XXX').removeClass('selected');`

Comment: +1 for suggesting using classes. As a rule, adding and removing classes is a better way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

You currently applying style to the td. Rather than you have tio apply css to the anchor tag.
Try this `$("#link-XXX a").css('font-weight', 'bold');`
It will work. If you want to add and remove classes, there is function addClass() and removeClass in jquery which you can use. Have a look at this [link](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest not complicating things so much, and using the changed class-name, in the css, to effect the change in font weight, rather than using jQuery to achieve much the same thing in a more complicated manner:

```
.link-xxx a {
    font-weight: bold;
}

/* or */

.link-xxx {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.link-xxx a {
    font-weight: inherit;
}
```